# CSS fixed position acts differently for different pages

Tags: html, css

I am using a scroll-and-fix function for my navigation bar and I switch between the following CSS classes when scrolling to a certain point:

```
.navbar_container{
    position:relative;
    width:101%;   
    left:0px;
}
    .fixed_position {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:84%;
    width:101%;
    left:-16px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

This was working perfectly for the navigation bar until I inserted a little change when the navbar includes different php scripts depends on user login. sometimes it includes the sign in option and when the user logs in it changes to "welcome username" kind of a thing. 
Here is the navbar code:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div class="container navbar_container ">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
            include 'includes/loggedin.php';
        } else{
            include 'includes/notloggedin.php';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here are the php scripts:

logged in:

```
</p><a class="logout_btn" href="Logout.php">Log Out</a><a   `href="edit_profile.php" class="edit_profile">Edit profile</a></span>`
```

not logged in:

```
<span id="login_menu"><a  href="Sign_in.php">Sign in</a></span>
```

So the problem is that the fixed position (after scrolling down) slightly changes between those states and thus I can't find the perfect position for both of those states to be fixed. I will provide any missing information if needed. thanks.

Comment: what you need exactly ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `php`?

Comment: And what are those backticks doing in the html line titled "logged in"?

Comment: @Naila I do not understand why would the fixed position won't act exactly the same for both php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Without any easy way to reproduce the issue it's merely a guess, but in the logged in code you're using a `p` tag, with default `display` of `inline-block`, and when not logged in, there's only `span`, which is default `display` of `inline`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand it further. both scripts are included in the navbar div container which is switched to fixed poisiton upon call. why would this effect the parent classes positions?

Comment: I can't get into that kind of detail without a complete, minimal, verifiable example that can reproduce the problem.  Can you build one as a js snippet?

Comment: Never did that before so let me look into it